# Android SaxParser cannot parse nbsp;

Tags: android, sax, atom-feed

I have been trying to fix this problem I am having with the SaxParser and an Atom Google Calendar feed. Basically the project that I am working on is pulling a Google Calendar feed from my college and placing it into a ListView, which when clicked opens up the entry in a new activity that displays all of the details of the Item the user selected. I believe that I've narrowed the problem down to a nbsp; being used in the atom feed. I have fixed similar processing issues with the title of each Item in the feed such as " and & with the String replaceAll method, but this has me stumped. The nbsp; is showing up as an Â(Circumflex A) used in many languages. It is not giving me an error and I guess if I cannot fix this the users could learn to live with it but it really bothers me that I cannot fix this. Stackoverflow is my last resort.

GIT: https://tylerjholmgren@bitbucket.org/tylerjholmgren/android-capstone-project.git

Above is the git location if you would like to take a look at my project. It will open in Android Studio/IntelliJ IDEA & Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Use the numeric equivalent:

Find: `&nbsp;`

Replace: `&#160;`

**References**

- [W3C Spec-Prod](http://dev.w3.org/cvsweb/spec-prod/)
- [W3C XML Specification DTD](http://xml.coverpages.org/XMLSpecDTD.html)
- [W3C XML Specification DTD: Characters and Symbols](http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/06/xmlspec.dtd#AEN2618)
- [Guide to the W3C XML Specification ("XMLspec") DTD, Version 2.1](http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/06/xmlspec-report)